# Logins error using sessions in php

Tags: php, session

I am using this script for my login system in php, while am handling the session values it is not working

Case is when am not validating the session values in the test page which are passed from index page the login is valid and goes to the test page after successful login but when am using the session values to validate in the test page the login is not successful, after entering the credentials the page does not goes to test.php it stays only on index.php

Can i know what is the mistake i have done ? Thanks in advance

**Login Page**

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';
error_reporting(0);
$employee_id = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['EMPLOYEE_ID']);
$password    = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['PASSWORD']);
$sql         = "SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID,EMP_NAME,DESG FROM EMPLOYEELOGIN WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID='" . $employee_id . "' AND PASSWORD='" . $password . "'";
$result      = $connection->query($sql);
session_start();
if ($result->num_rows == 1) {
    $row                     = $result->fetch_row();
    // print_r($row);
    $_SESSION['EMPLOYEE_ID'] = $row[0];
    $_SESSION['EMPNAME']     = $row[1];
    $_SESSION['DESG']        = $row[2];
    header('Location: test.php');
}
?>

// The form used
<form role="form" method="post" action='index.php' class="m-t-20">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="EMPLOYEE_ID" required="" placeholder="Username">

  <input class="form-control" type="password" name="PASSWORD" required="" placeholder="Password">

  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

**Test Page**

```
<?php
session_start();
// error_reporting(0);
if (isset($_SESSION['EMPLOYEE_ID'])) {
    if ($_SESSION['EMP_NAME'] != 1) {
        header("Location: index.php");
    } else {
        require 'connection.php';
    }
} else {
    header("Location: index.php");
}
?>
```

**connection.php**

```
<?php
$connection = new mysqli("localhost","root","123","testdatabase");
if($connection->connect_error){
    die("Connection Failed<br>".$connection->connect_error);
}
?>
```

Comment: I edited your question to remove code that was not needed for people to help you. Generally you should provide just enough code. For this question that means just the form and the relating PHP code, all the other html markup scripts etc are just a distraction.

Comment: Please don't store `passwords` as plain text. Have a look at [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to properly store your passwords

Answer (score 0):

Updated Answer based on new connection.php code::

You do not appear to have a mysqli class included in the code anywhere so your attempt to instantiate will fail, you should be getting a white page or an error of some sort depending on your php.ini configurations. In any of the code I assume you do not have that class. If thats the case you need to convert your code over to use mysqli_ functions directly or create/install a mysqli class. Direct functions you would use like this:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect // etc...
```

-------------- Previous Answer --------------

PASSWORD is a reserved word in mysql

```
PASSWORD=
```

Should be (note the backticks)

```
`PASSWORD`=
```

Or better yet, change the name of the column to something like user_password, pass or anything you want.

I believe that will solve the problem.

There is a full list of reserved words for mysql available here:

[Mysql Keywords/Reserved Words List](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html)

Comment: I have made the changes as per your suggestion but there is no change same issue repeats @Chris

Comment: @SairamDuggi Can you update your question with the relevant code in your connection.php file, remove private data of course.

Comment: @SairamDuggi Updated